# Symfony : Turn off cache using config.yml not working

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I am new to **Symfony** and working on a project for UI changes. But I am not able to see my change on the screen. However when I delete the cache files using ***app/cache*** manually then it works But this is not a feasible way to delete cache manually every time.

I also try to turn off the cache using via ***app/config/congig.yml*** under **twig:** *cache: false* but its not work.

I have only FTP for the website So I am not able use command line interface.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Access the site through `/app_dev.php/%normal path%` and no cache will be used. Though you might need to add your remote ip to the list of allowed ips in that file.

Comment: @Yoshi, Let me check

Comment: @Yoshi, when I try to access homepage, it is showing "You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information".

Comment: See the last part of my comment :)

Comment: Still Not working. Or I am not getting your point ? :(

Comment: @Yoshi, I am trying to access it "www.example.com/app_dev.php/contact". But it return the same error

Comment: `app_dev.php` is guarded against open access. So if you want to access it from a remote address you will need to add your ip to the list of allowed ip addresses. It's the array that starts with something like: `['127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1', ...]`. Meaning you need to actually edit the file and add your address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent twig (and other system caches) simply access your app in dev-mode. Do do this, instead of the normal url, e.g.:

```
example.com/foo/bar
```

use:

```
example.com/app_dev.php/foo/bar
```

*(provided the app root is at `example.com`)*

---

Note that to do this from anything but localhost, you'll need to update `app_dev.php` to include your remote address. The relevant line looks something like:

```
!(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1',
```

It's very advisable to revert this change, once you're done with your work.

---

**Further reading**:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html#executing-an-application-in-different-environments

Comment: Thank You @Yoshi :)